# Consuming WCF in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-3.5, asp.net-2.0

My application is in asp.net 2.0. Is it possible to consume WCF service developed in asp.net 3.5? If possible, how can we consume wcf service in asp.net 2.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the WCF service in question exposes a basic http endpoint, you should be able to connect to it from an ASP.NET 2.0 website as if it was a web service.  Simply right-click the ASP.NET 2.0 project in Visual Studio, and select "Add Web Reference" - this will startup the wizard that can generate a proxy for you to consume the WCF service as if it is simply a web service.